# Winapi EDITTEXT can't paste

Tags: c++, winapi, textbox

In a cpp project, I have an EDITTEXT in a resource file and I would like to allow user paste some text in it. I can paste using right click but not with the 'ctrl+v' shortcut.

```
EDITTEXT        IDC_EDITTAN, 90, 46, 80, 12, ES_AUTOHSCROLL
```

It seems that no edit control styles or rich edit control styles allow this (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774367(v=vs.85).aspx).

I have to make a callback or use an other controller ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, the message for `ctrl-v` is catched by a parent window.

Check your accelerator table in resource view, or `ACCELERATORS` in the resource file to see if one is in there. Removing it should solve the problem.