# Add custom controller to DialogBox: Faillure on Create

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I have to make a custom controller "MyCEdit" inherited from CEdit. I just want to push my custom controller in a dialogbox but the window crash on create. I saw the documention [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6zxw3b4a.aspx) and made some adjustement :

On InitDialog  I have:

```
if (message == WM_INITDIALOG)
{
    CWnd* pWnd = CWnd::FromHandle(hwndDlg);

    MyCEdit* pEdit = new MyCEdit();
    pEdit->Create(WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP | WS_BORDER,
        CRect(10, 10, 100, 100), pWnd, IDC_CUSTOM_EDIT1); /* Failure here */
    return TRUE;
}
```

I Have check the pointer `pWnd`, he's not `NULL` and point to the good window. And `pEdit` is not `NULL`.

My custom controller looks like (only override the `PreTranslateMessage` method):

```
class MyCEdit : public CEdit
{
public:
    BOOL PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg) override
    {
        if (pMsg->message == WM_KEYDOWN && ::GetKeyState(VK_CONTROL) != 0)
        {
            switch (pMsg->wParam)
            {
            case 'X': Cut(); return TRUE;
            case 'C': Copy(); return TRUE;
            case 'V': Paste(); return TRUE;
            case 'Z': Undo(); return TRUE;
            case 'A': SetSel(0, -1); return TRUE;
            }
        }
        return CEdit::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
    }
};
```

There is a step I miss or I make a wrong operation ?

Comment: A standard Edit control supports cut/copy/paste, unless you broke it. Consider fixing the issue, instead of working around it by fighting the system. Your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34655741/1889329) suggests, that you should check your accelerators.

Comment: I make a plugin for a program, I can't acess to these accelerators. I've tried this solution to make my own but it doesn't work.

Comment: GetActiveWindow() does not return you a handle to your dialog, too early.  Why are you not using the hDlg argument of your callback function?

Comment: You right, I don't have to use `GetActiveWindow`, I change it but same failure.

Comment: Re: "On InitDialog I have:" - what is `InitDialog`? In MFC, you have `virtual BOOL OnInitDialog();` that you implement in your dialog class. You don't need to test for `if (message == WM_INITDIALOG)` there...